# AngularJs function returns wrong window.location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having this angularJs script to pass me to my view where the Url will be: www.mySite.com/blogg/1
It works fine if I am on my startPage (www.mySite.com). When the function gets hit it takes me to www.mySite.com/blogg/1.

But the problem is when I then are on one of my blogPages (www.mySite.com/blogg/1). Then when my function gets hit to take me to another blogPage the Url that renders is for example: www.mySite.com/blogg/blogg/2

Hoq can I remove the extra /blogg part so it renders as i want: www.myPage.com/blogg/2 ?

```
$scope.goToRequestedPost = function (id) {
    console.log(id);
    {
        $http.post("/Home/SingleBlogPost", { postId: id }).success(function () {
                window.location = "blogg/" + id;      
        });
    }
};
```

//Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the following:

```
// similar behavior as using HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("/blogg/" + id);

// similar behavior as when clicking on a link
window.location.href = "/blogg/" + id;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your soution works for me! I used the replace-part!

Answer (score 0):

use the service $location (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

$location.path("blogg/" + id);

Comment: thanks for your answer. Tried this but it doesn't work. Could you give me som more info how I can use if?

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend '/' to make the path relative to the domain root instead your current location.

```
 window.location = "/blogg/" + id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Iv'e tried this, but it doesn't' work. Could you please give me some more info, if theres somthing I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's better, as user32348 suggested, to use Angular methods instead of using window.location. I had some problems using window.location inside an Angular application when using Internet Explorer https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2007